# Como criar um webgrid com colunas dinâmicas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Vi vários exemplos usando WebGrid mas todos com a quantidade de colunas fixas. Minha fonte de dados vai retorna uma lista dinâmica, ou seja, ora retorna 5 colunas e depois pode retornar 6 colunass, como fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 5, canPage: true);

    List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    cols.Add(grid.Column("ColunaManual", "Coluna Manual"));
    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> linha in Model.Select(m => m.ToPropertyDictionary()))
    {
        cols.Add(grid.Column(linha.Key, linha.Key, 
            format: item => Html.Raw("<text>" + linha.Value + "</text>")
        ));
    }
}
```

`ToPropertyDictionary()` está aqui:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions 
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToPropertyDictionary(this object obj)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                dictionary[propertyInfo.Name] = (propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) ?? "").ToString();
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: entendi, o `Modelo` é convertido em um tipo `Dictionary`, mas agora eu me dei conta do seguinte: os dados com a quantidade dinâmica de atributos virão de uma **Procedure** e como fazer um **Modelo** pra refletir essa quantidade dinâmica de atributos ? Tem como ?, por exemplo na classe de contexto terei que fazer algo assim: `modelBuilder.Entity<Documento>().MapToStoredProcedures();`. Os dados veêm de um a procedure devido a uma função Pivot que é utilizado nessa proc.

Comment: Faça outra pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Obrigado @Cigano Morrison Mendez eu criei um nova pergunta [link] https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205530/atributos-din%C3%A2mico-de-um-modelo-entidade [link] .