# Atributos dinâmico de um Modelo Entidade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma **procedure** que retorna uma quantidade de colunas **dinâmicas**, pois essa procedure utiliza da função [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), daí então surge a dúvida: 
Como criar um **Modelo Entidade** para essa procedure ?. 
Exemplo:

```
public class SProcedure_EF6Context : DbContext
{    
    public SProcedure_EF6Context() : base("name=SProcedure_EF6Context")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Medico> Medicos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Criar as Stored Procedures
        modelBuilder.Entity<Medico>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.MapToStoredProcedures()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237184(v=vs.113).aspx) é uma coisa. Mapear uma *stored procedure* com retorno dinâmico é outra.

Usamos `.MapToStoredProcedures()` quando queremos que o Entity Framework não gere SQL, e sim que gere *stored procedures* e as chame nas operações de persistência. Isso é comum quando o banco de dados teria problemas conhecidos de performance, como tabelas grandes demais e volume de dados intenso, em que vale a pena empenhar dispositivos do próprio banco de dados para otimizar as operações.

No seu caso, o que você quer é obter um retorno dinâmico de uma *stored procedure* usando o Entity Framework. De antemão já digo que isso não é possível, a não ser que você pegue a relação de colunas de um retorno e gere um objeto em tempo de execução. Não é muito prático e a implementação é insana.

Portanto, para resolver, será necessário um esquema que preveja um retorno dinâmico. ADO.NET é uma opção. [Dapper também](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Farei uma sugestão nesta resposta e você depois decide qual o melhor caminho a seguir.

## ADO.NET

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MinhaProcedure", contexto.Database.Connection) 
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

## Dapper

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> resultados = db.Database.Connection.Query("MinhaProcedure", new { Param1 = 1, Param2 = "2" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```